# Help understanding a problem with inclusion/exclusion

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I am trying to understand how to use inclusion/exclusion in algorithm.

I think I understand the basic example of what the inclusion/exclusion principle is: the principle is in general illustrated using a venn diagram and the objective is counting the elements of the sets. The principle says that ou first over-count the intersections, then exclude the intersections, then include the intersections of the intersections...

I can see the logic in this formula, and what it achieves.

```
|A ∪ B ∪ C| = |A| + |B| + |C| − |A ∩ B| − |A ∩ C| − |B ∩ C| + |A ∩ B ∩ C|
```

My object is to understand how to use IE as to resolve other problems than the above. I know it is possible to use it to solve problems such as: #Ordered Set Partitions, Graph Colouring, #Bipartite Perfect Matchings, Counting Hamiltonian Cycles, etc.. as I find it in literature. E.g.: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.2942v2.pdf

But when I read the paper above, I can understand only problem 6 which is related to the same sets counting problem as above. Somehow, I cannot seem to grasp the concept of how IE is used to solve any other problem than the above.

Would someone please be able to explain the IE principle using an example different than the set counting? Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, the article on Wikipedia contains many examples, includign some that don't rely on set notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle.  What's wrong with those examples?  Where have you looked?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research/self-study before asking, and to show us in the question what you've done.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question, thanks for accepting the edit. I attempted to clarify what I am after in my edit. Basically, I can understand that the IE principle has several other applications other than set counting, however I just cannot grasp the application in other problems thus was asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Inclusion-exclusion only "does" set counting and all but one of your examples are exactly that: you have a set of objects (ordered set partitions, bipartite perfect matchings, Hamiltonian cycles, etc.) and the paper shows how to count the objects in that set using inclusion-exclusion. In the fourth example, the author uses inclusion-exclusion to prove that a $k$-colouring exists if, and only if, some counting condition is satisfied.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. My question is more specifically that counting elements of a set seems like a natural problem which I understand using IE. On the other hand, for all the others you mentioned I fail to understand. Suppose "ordered set partitions", how can I count these using IE? Moreover, suppose "Hamiltonian cycles": at some point algorithm has to check if a given result is really a hamiltonian cycle or not - so how can one just count them using IE? Where the checking is performed?

Comment: Apologies for such a general question. I guess if one could pick one of the other problems and attempt to go stepwise it would help me understand. I just cannot visualise the IE technique being applied to the other examples. Again, thanks.